# Microsoft Graph API throwing exception

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, membership

since two days I get an exception calling :

```
var usersInGroup = await graphClient.Groups[groupid].Members.Request().GetAsync();

{
  "error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "4069215a-945f-4cc0-abbf-132d703f55ae",
      "date": "2020-04-28T08:18:49"
    }
  }
}
```

This call always worked before and proper permissions are given and consented.

Is there any known issue with this API / service ?
Any easy way to debug / monitor calls in Azure portal ?

best regards
Rainer

Comment: Hi Rainer, are you facing this issue with the West Europe, Germany central regions? I am also facing this issue only in above regions. It is working fine in UK South and other regions.

Comment: No, it is independent of the region and was fix by removing the Group.Selected permission .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems like an Application permission `Group.Selected` that affects the calling of this API endpoint `/memberOf`. Removing this permission will fix the issue.

Comment: Hi @RainerHartmann you can accept the answer so that it will be useful to others

Comment: HI @ Saurabh Srivastava, thanks for pointing me to the accept.

Answer (score 0):

just saw your problem - I'm having the same issue: [MS-Graph request: insufficient privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61479622/ms-graph-request-insufficient-privileges)
You may want to change your tag to 'microsoft-graph' so that it is found easier.

Comment: Since you face the same issue, it seems the API is broken. I also use app permissions. It has been working before for at least 6 months, since then no changes in this code